# Android/Java: How to inherit from a class into an activity that extends AppCompatActivity?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I am quite new to Android, and I don't know how to inherit from the class 'HereMapClass', in my case, into an activity 'HereMap' that extends AppCompatActivity?

I think there is code in double, the goal is to have the main class that inherit all the functions of the HereMapClass. I would like to get the class HereMapClass to manage the download of map etc... and the main class just to manage the map visually on the phone in a fragment. I did it that way because I need to use the class separate as I use it in multiple place in the code but without needing to display the map visually.

Here is the code of the Main class :

**HereMap Class activity:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class HereMap extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView view;
    private AndroidXMapFragment mapFragment = null;
    private MapRoute m_mapRoute;
    JSONArray jsonPoints;
    JSONArray jsArray;
    ArrayList<String> poiArr;
    String gpsFolder;
    String poiFolder;
    String loopName = "";
    String loopLang = "";
    String loopEvent = "";

    Context mContext;
    Intent intent;
    Bundle bundle2;


    private final static String TAG = HereMap.class.getSimpleName();
    private MapView mapView;
    private Map map;
    private static Image m_marker_image;
    //MapScreenMarker m_tap_marker;
    MapMarker m_tap_marker2;
    private ArrayList<MapPackage> currentInstalledMaps;
    private String currentInstalledMapsString;
    private ProgressBar downloadProgressBar;
    private PositioningManager positioningManager = null;
    private PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener positionListener;
    private GeoCoordinate currentPosition;


    // listener for MapLoader
    private MapLoader.Listener mapLoaderHandler = new MapLoader.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgress(int progress) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Progress " + progress + "%");
            downloadProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInstallationSize(long diskSize, long networkSize) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Map data require " + diskSize);
        }

        @Override
        public void onGetMapPackagesComplete(MapPackage rootMapPackage,
                                             MapLoader.ResultCode resultCode) {
            if (resultCode == MapLoader.ResultCode.OPERATION_SUCCESSFUL) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Map packages received successful: " + rootMapPackage.getTitle());

                currentInstalledMaps = new ArrayList<>(1);
                populateInstalledMaps(rootMapPackage);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Can't retrieve map packages: " + resultCode.name());
                Toast.makeText(HereMap.this,
                        "Error: " + resultCode.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (MapPackage pac : currentInstalledMaps) {
                sb.append(pac.getTitle());
                sb.append("\n");
            }

            currentInstalledMapsString = sb.toString();
        }


        private void populateInstalledMaps(MapPackage pac) {
            // only take installed root package, so if e.g. Germany is installed,
            // don't check for children states
            if (pac.getInstallationState() == MapPackage.InstallationState.INSTALLED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Installed package found: " + pac.getTitle() + " id " + pac.getId());
                currentInstalledMaps.add(pac);
            } else if (pac.getChildren() != null && pac.getChildren().size() > 0) {
                for (MapPackage p : pac.getChildren()) {
                    populateInstalledMaps(p);
                }
            }
        }
...
```

Here is the class to inherit into the main one:

**HereMapClass:**

```
public class HereMapClass {

    private MapView view;
    private AndroidXMapFragment mapFragment = null;
    private MapRoute m_mapRoute;
    private  MapEngine mapEngine;
    private MapLoader mapLoader;

    JSONArray jsonPoints;
    JSONArray jsArray;
    ArrayList<String> poiArr;
    String gpsFolder;
    String poiFolder;
    String loopName = "";
    String loopLang = "";
    String loopEvent = "";

    Context mContext;
    Intent intent;
    Bundle bundle2;


    private final static String TAG = HereMap.class.getSimpleName();
    private MapView mapView;
    private Map map;
    private static Image m_marker_image;
    //MapScreenMarker m_tap_marker;
    MapMarker m_tap_marker2;
    private ArrayList<MapPackage> currentInstalledMaps;
    private String currentInstalledMapsString;
    private ProgressBar downloadProgressBar;
    private PositioningManager positioningManager = null;
    private PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener positionListener;
    private GeoCoordinate currentPosition;

    private Context context;

    public HereMapClass(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    // listener for MapLoader
    private MapLoader.Listener mapLoaderHandler = new MapLoader.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(int progress) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Progress " + progress + "%");
                downloadProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInstallationSize(long diskSize, long networkSize) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Map data require " + diskSize);
            }

            @Override
            public void onGetMapPackagesComplete(MapPackage rootMapPackage,
                                                 MapLoader.ResultCode resultCode) {
                if (resultCode == MapLoader.ResultCode.OPERATION_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Map packages received successful: " + rootMapPackage.getTitle());

                    currentInstalledMaps = new ArrayList<>(1);

                    populateInstalledMaps(rootMapPackage);


                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Can't retrieve map packages: " + resultCode.name());
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Error: " + resultCode.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (MapPackage pac : currentInstalledMaps) {
                    sb.append(pac.getTitle());
                    sb.append("\n");
                }

                currentInstalledMapsString = sb.toString();
            }


            private void populateInstalledMaps(MapPackage pac) {
                // only take installed root package, so if e.g. Germany is installed,
                // don't check for children states
                if (pac.getInstallationState() == MapPackage.InstallationState.INSTALLED) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Installed package found: " + pac.getTitle() + " id " + pac.getId());
                    currentInstalledMaps.add(pac);
                } else if (pac.getChildren() != null && pac.getChildren().size() > 0) {
                    for (MapPackage p : pac.getChildren()) {
                        populateInstalledMaps(p);
                    }
                }

                //continuez à installer
                //lancer notification pour login
                
            }
...
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is multiple inheritance. You want a class to inherit from **both**  `HereMapClass` and `AppCompatActivity`. That isn't possible in Java as Java language does not support multiple inheritance.

Since you are building an `Activity`, you **must** inherit from `AppCompatActivity`. Therefore, to use `HereMapClass` you will need to use delegation instead of inheritance.

Create an instance of `HereMapClass` and store a reference in a member variable in your `Activity`. When you want to use `HereMapClass`, simply call methods on your instance of the class.

Basically, you are "delegating" some responsibility to the instance of `HereMapClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Use delegation instead of inheritance.
Unlike some other object oriented programming languages, Java doesn’t provide support for multiple inheritance in classes. More info on that: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/multiple-inheritance-in-java

For your use case, you could create an interface (ignore the naming :))

```
    public interface HereMap {
    void onProgress();
    void populateInstalledMaps();
}
```

Create an implementation of that interface:

```
public class IHereMapImpl implements IHereMap {
    @Override
    public void onProgress() {
        //add logic
    }

    @Override
    public void populateInstalledMaps() {
        ////add logic
    }
}
```

use this interface around where you need:

public class HereMap extends AppCompatActivity  {

```
    private IHereMap iHereMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        iHereMap = new IHereMapImpl();
        iHereMap.onProgress();
        iHereMap.populateInstalledMaps();
    }
}
```

Recommendation: [Android Architecture Guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture?gclid=CjwKCAiA9qKbBhAzEiwAS4yeDYhM1SDEvczGfGyydvS7dB_itgk7EHSBEr0dpBoKK_VZv9mNtMGVbxoCk8EQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Hope it helps :)